# Getting specific columns from Database with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have this database :

```
Users:
-idUser
-login
-password
-email

Relationship:
-idUser
-idFriend
```

And in my models i have this :

```
public class User
{
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false), Display(Name = "ID user")]
    public int idUser { set; get; }
    [StringLength(16), Display(Name = "Login")]
    public string login{ set; get; }
    [StringLength(16), Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password{ set; get; }
    [StringLength(64), Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string email{ set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> friends{ get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        friends = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

And I created this code in my context to enable the self referencing many to many relationships :

```
public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(m => m.friends).WithMany().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("idUser");
            m.MapRightKey("idFriend");
            m.ToTable("Relationship");
        });       
    }
```

And this part of code in my controller to respond to users requests :

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public User getMyInformations([FromBody] String[] data)
{
    string login = data[0];
    string password = data[1];
    Utilisateur me = null;
    User user = db.Users.Where<User>(u => u.login.Equals(login)).FirstOrDefault<User>();
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.password.Equals(password))
        {
            me = user;
        }
    }
    return me;
}
```

And finally i added this instruction in Global.asax to avoid Self referencing loop :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Re‌ferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Every thing work fine but i have a little problem : when I want to send Json to client side the Json looks like this :

```
{"friends":[{"friends":[],"idUser":2,"login":"user2","password":"1234",
 "email":"user2@gmail.com"],"idUser":1,"login":"user1","password":"0000",
 "email":"myEamil@gmail.com",}
```

but i dont like to send confidential information about the friends collection like the password to the user !
I think I can solve this by adding this code in my controller :

```
if (user.password.Equals(password))
{
    me = user;
    //adding this code :
    foreach (User friend in me.friends)
    {
        friend.password = null;
        //friend.email= null;
    }
}
```

but I'm looking for most significant way to do it !
I hope there is a way to prevent EF from getting some columns from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to specify what to select for the user's friends you could simply add that:

```
var user = db.Users
             .Where(u => u.login.Equals(login))
             .Select(usr => new {
                 login = usr.login,
                 email = usr.email,
                 friends = usr.Friends.Select(fr => new {
                     // your friend info here Ex.:
                     email = fr.email,
                 })
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, now its working like what I'm expecting ! note that you have to remove the "ToList()" method because it's raising an exception : "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Collections.Generic.List..... method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 2):

erkaner's answer is correct although you can do it with anonymous object as well

```
var user = db.Users
                  .Where(u => u.login.Equals(login))
                  .Select(usr => new {
                      login = usr.login,
                      email = usr.email,
                      //basically include what you want
                  })                  
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is what I'd do too. Though note that you can remove the User type specifier on the Where method and the member names in the anonymous type - they can both be inferred by the compiler.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that, sorry. Fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new view class for User that does not contain the password property, lets say it is called UserView class.

```
UserView user = db.Users
              .Where<User>(u =>u .login.Equals(login))
              .Select(uw => new UserView () 
                  {
                      login = u.login,
                      email = u.email,
                      //do not include password here
                  }
              )                  
              .FirstOrDefault<User>();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying but I found better solution for my case, the answers of Martin Shishkov and erkaner didn't solved my problem because they are just preventing EF of getting the user password not the passwords in friends collection.
I've created a view in my database called UserViews which contains the public informations of the users (in this case UserViews doesn't contain password attribute) and I've created a model called UserView having the public attributes too, and I've changed the friends collection in User model like this :

```
public virtual ICollection<UserView> friends{ get; set; }
```

and it works like what I'm expecting !